# Split characters in a string with a comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to write a regex function that return all of the digits in a comma separated string:

```
function printDigits() {
   var result = sentence.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').split(",")
    console.log(result)
}
```

But it just prints out a string instead of digits being separated by comma. Are there any ways I can fix this?

Input: "5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5."

Expected output: "5,3,1,7,3,0,5,5,1,9,3,5"

Comment: Please provide sample input and output

Comment: `sentence.match(/\d/g)`? `sentence.match(/\d/g).join(",")`?

Answer (score 2):

`split` doesn't work this way. It splits by the separator that is *already in the input*. To split string to individual characters use `split('')`, and then join individual characters with comma:

```
   var result = sentence.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').split('').join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
sentence.match(/\d/g).join(",")
```

Here,

- `sentence.match(/\d/g)` - extracts each separate digit from string
- `.join(",")` - join the array items into a single comma-delimited string.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var sentence = "5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5.";
console.log(sentence.match(/\d/g).join(","));
// -> 5,3,1,7,3,0,5,5,1,9,3,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation that uses pure regex and does not require a `.join()` call:

```
sentence.replace(/\D+|(\d)(?=\d)/g, '$1,');
```

This replaces any string of non-digit characters with a comma. And it also locates the position between two digits and adds a comma between them.

**Pattern breakdown:**

- `\D+` - Match one or more non-digit characters.
- `|` - OR...
- `(\d)` - Match one digit and capture it in group 1.
- `(?=\d)` - Followed by another digit.
- Substition:

  - `$1,` - Replace with whatever was captured in group 1, plus a comma.

Here's a full demo:

```js
var sentence = "5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5";
var result = sentence.replace(/\D+|(\d)(?=\d)/g, '$1,');
console.log(result); // 5,3,1,7,3,0,5,5,1,9,3,5
```

Answer (score 0):

A [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) solution

```js
const x = `5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5`
  .split('')
  .reduce((acc, val) =>
    val.trim().length && !isNaN(+val) ? [...acc, +val] : acc, []);
console.log(`${x}`);
```

Or simply

```js
console.log(`${`5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5`.match(/\d/g)}`);
```